What old teen movie is this?
I've been racking my brain for many years trying to figure out what movie this was from, you can probably understand just how hard it has been to try to Google this when i only remember a few scenes from the movie:
It was a collage road trip sort of movie i believe where a class or group of students went on a trip with their teacher/s.
*In one scene the movies "fat and stupid" guy is bugging the leader/teacher who is talking to the receptionist at the place so either the leader or the receptionist takes a handful of candies/mints and throws on the ground behind them to make the fat guy run after it.
*In one scene the students have spiked the "hot teacher"s chocolate box with liquor to try to get her to strip in front of a two-way mirror, and one student is sent in to sort of seduce the drunk teacher.
*I believe there was one super creepy nerd who had a cardboard cutout of some actor who he worshiped.
I'm sorry to be so vague, we rented this movie on VHS so long ago and this is literally the only scenes i remember.

Hi. Do you know the approximate year\decade of release? The country\language?

You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Sounds like "Senior Trip" 

"At Fairmount High School in Columbus, Ohio, a debauched group of kids rule over the school, led by stoners Mark 'Dags' D'Agastino and Reggie Barry, who preach partying over education. When Dags and Reggie, along with a small assorted group of kids are caught cutting school and throwing a house party in the whiny and incompetent Principal Moss' house, they are put into detention where they are asked to write a letter to the President of the USA on the problems with education. Yet, only the school 'brainiac' Lisa Perkins writes it and mails it where it's a hit with the President who invites them to Washington on a field trip to speak for education reforms. With Principal Moss and the new keyboarding teacher, Miss Milford, chaperoning them, Dags and Reggie, along with Lisa, shy stoner Wanda, school tramp Carla, king geek Virus, biker chick Meg, quiet poet Herbert, narc Steve, and the 'stupid fat kid' Miosky, take an eventual bus trip to Washington... if they can ever get there."

There is a scene where the students lace a box of the principal's chocolates with tequila:

"That night back at the hotel, the seniors secretly lace a box of chocolates with tequila and give it to Miss Milford, subsequently leaving and going to a party at another hotel while Miss Milford seduces Principal Moss in a drunken stupor. In the process, Lisa Perkins (Fiona Loewi) discovers the plot to use the students to embarrass the President." 

Preview:



